# Why might an ajax-based page load be slower than a full load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been working for a few months on loading most pages of our website with ajax, using jQuery and history.js (https://github.com/browserstate/history.js). Technically this has been working very well, there are no serious issues. The basic process is:

1. bind handlers to clicks
2. on clicks, prevent default and do a History.pushState

Then on statechange:

1. scroll to top, showing a loading animation
2. hide the main content div, then erase it's contents with a .empty()
3. run the ajax request ($.post to the target URL)
4. when data is received, put it in the main content div, show that div, and hide the loading animation

Note that I'm specifically changing the request to a post instead of a get, because I need to send a post flag telling the server that this is an ajax request, so it knows to only return the necessary content.

However, google analytics reports that the page load times are, on average, about 1 second longer for users with ajax browsing turned on (I'm doing a 50/50 split test).

For a while I assumed this was just inaccurate reporting, because I've read that google's speed reports can get very screwed up by one or two visitors from across the globe who get longer load times.

Today I opened two browser windows side by side (chrome and chrome incognito) and clicked around the site, and sure enough the window using ajax did have somewhat slower load times. It wasn't consistent, sometimes it was faster, but never by a lot. When it was slower, it was significantly slower. Usually this happened when the ajax request just seemed to be slow (the loading animation remained visible for an extra second or so). Meanwhile the full load window had consistent load times.

I can't imagine why this would be the case. The ajax request should always be faster. Anyone encounter this before and discover the same thing?

Comment: Wouldn't the AJAX load will require a "full load" anyway? You're basically performing an additional request. What am I missing? :/

Comment: What I can think of: DOM manipulations are expensive. Erasing and dynamically loading a large chunk of your DOM will probably take some time.

Comment: @Mike-Willis AJAX calls are not inherently faster.  They appear to be fast only because they are supposed to handle smaller pieces of the page (hence shorter request/response).  However, multiple calls (i.e. request/responses) can make a page slower (when compared to a single request/response) so it really depends.  Browser-cache aside, your AJAX steps seem reasonable and it should be faster but the testing might be askewed.  Try multiple AJAX tests from a browser and get the average.  Then, do multiple tests (non-AJAX) and get the average. (con't)

Comment: Then try to extract DOM manipulations times (log them if you must) and get only server-side request/response times.  It may lead you somewhere

Comment: @CaseyFalk This technique may mitigate the time to parse Javascript and CSS files again and again. This does nothing to execution time of the server and the pos. effects might be subtle. One might also run into issues, if the solution is not implemented well. [Rails has some standard functionality for this called Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks). Instead of creating a new custom solution, one might use that. (Or at least take a sneak at [their Javascript code](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)...)

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the explanation, @GhostGambler.

Comment: My first guess would be that you have to load the page from server (first call-probably non-AJAX) then load the page do the request(second call) than parse the AJAX response then change the DOM and parse any css/JS script added from the second call. As oppose to (Not sure this is entirely true) do the first call then load the page then send a request then load another page. So in both case there's two request made from the sever but in the AJAX the browser to execute the AJAX call and parse the response as oppose to the non-AJAX where the server do most of the work.

Comment: Ok, maybe my comment wasn't so clear. All I wanted to say is that since AJAX calls are executed browser-side and that response is parse browser-side it might be a bit slower than if the server would have done most of the work.

Comment: @blurfus Thanks, I'll do some tinkering along the lines of what you suggested. Google gives me similar numbers but I'd like to do my own test too. Google says the Document Interactive Time, Document Content Loaded Time, and Page Load Time are all slower with ajax on, but server interactions like Server Connection, Server Response etc are all just about the same. I still can't imagine why it's slower - the browser is getting only a portion of the data in the ajax request, and this portion is exactly the same as what a full page load would send.

Comment: @Sebastien With ajax on, the first page load is exactly the same as a normal page load, there's no ajax in this case. The following page loads use ajax to only load the internal content (leaving the header, nav, and footer the same). The response being parsed browser-side on the ajax call is exactly the same as what the browser would have to parse on a full page load, it's just a small portion of it. For example a full page load has to process items 0 through 100, but an ajax request of the same URL only has to process items 40 through 80. In both cases, items 40 through 80 are processed.

Comment: @MikeWillis not quite sure if I am going on full retard on this but you'd have to get the js code for the ajax code somewhere... Lets see if I understand correctly: 1-Send a http request to get AJAX code 2-AJAX code run make the AJAX call 3-Parse the response with javascript browser-side 4-Change DOM accordingly etc. as for non-AJAX: 1- Send an http request 2-Browser submit 3-Process data and send back whole page with DOM changed 4-Load the newly Changed DOM  I am correct to assume this describes mostly the situation or I am stupid and didn't get at all what the h**l you were talking about???

Comment: @Sebastien It's a bit different than what you listed. Non-Ajax = 1. get full page. That's it, no more steps. This will only happen on the first page view. The next page view will use ajax, because now the user has downloaded all of our scripts, as well as our header/nav/footer. So a click to any other page will: 1. erase main content on the current page. 2. make ajax request. 3. receive data (usually a bunch of HTML). 4. place the received data in the main content section of the current page, then unhide main content.

Comment: Yep exactly what I am saying your browser probably execute code way slower then your server thus making your AJAX request slower. If you weren't using AJAX you'd be doing 1- get full page. 2- Parse next content to load server-side. 3-display the usual bunch of HTML. There is less steps non-AJAX and your server can probably do the executing and parsing way faster than your browser which more time for the AJAX way since you execute code slower on browser side and have to get through more steps.

Comment: It would be different if you'd have a small quantity of data since then your browser would have way less data to execute and parse then the server with a full HTML page.